Starting Expert Mode of Display Calibrator Assistant in macOS 14
How do we get into the "Expert Mode" of Display Calibrator.app on macOS 14 and beyond?

Those who think this is a duplicate question should read more carefully. The one they think this is a duplicate of is over four years old and the process for starting EXPERT mode is not the same. This is most certainly not a duplicate.
